# Android Studio - Get the recorded Sound Level

Tags: java, android, audio, record

I am trying to build an app which amongst other things, has a sound recording functionality. I have followed the guide from the Android Developer Documentation found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder), and created the **AudioRecordTest** Class containing the following code:

```
package com.example.ssresilience;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.io.IOException;

public class AudioRecordTest extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
    private static final int REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION = 200;
    private static String fileName = null;

    private RecordButton recordButton = null;
    private MediaRecorder recorder = null;

    private PlayButton playButton = null;
    private MediaPlayer player = null;

    // Requesting permission to RECORD_AUDIO
    private boolean permissionToRecordAccepted = false;
    private String [] permissions = {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION:
                permissionToRecordAccepted  = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                break;
        }
        if (!permissionToRecordAccepted ) finish();

    }

    private void onRecord(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startRecording();
        } else {
            stopRecording();
        }
    }

    private void onPlay(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startPlaying();
        } else {
            stopPlaying();
        }
    }

    private void startPlaying() {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            player.setDataSource(fileName);
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }

    void startRecording() {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        recorder.start();
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
    }

    class RecordButton extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton {
        boolean mStartRecording = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onRecord(mStartRecording);
                if (mStartRecording) {
                    setText("Stop recording");
                } else {
                    setText("Start recording");
                }
                mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
            }
        };

        public RecordButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Start recording");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);
        }
    }

    class PlayButton extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton {
        boolean mStartPlaying = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onPlay(mStartPlaying);
                if (mStartPlaying) {
                    setText("Stop playing");
                } else {
                    setText("Start playing");
                }
                mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;
            }
        };

        public PlayButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Start playing");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        // Record to the external cache directory for visibility
        fileName = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
        fileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        recordButton = new RecordButton(this);
        ll.addView(recordButton,
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        0));
        playButton = new PlayButton(this);
        ll.addView(playButton,
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        0));
        getAmplitude();
        setContentView(ll);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (recorder != null) {
            recorder.release();
            recorder = null;
        }

        if (player != null) {
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The recording start / stop process, as well as the audio playback using the Media Player appear to be working just fine, but in my case this is not exactly what I want to achieve.

I wish to somehow implement a function in this example, which returns the recorder sound level (maybe in decibels?) as soon as I tap "Stop Recording", and then print it. I have looked at many other examples, but none of them seem to work since the app crashes as soon as the method to start recording is called. With that in mind, this is why I would like to stick to this example.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

I had to call the method `getMaxAmplitude()` on both the start and stop methods, like so:

```
    void startRecording() {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }
        recorder.start();
        audiolevel = recorder.getMaxAmplitude();
        System.out.println(audiolevel);
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        audiolevelprocessed = recorder.getMaxAmplitude();
        System.out.println(audiolevelprocessed);
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
    }
```

This stores and prints the Max Amplitude twice, with the first one always being 0. If it doesn't exist on both methods I always get 0 as a print value. Not entirely sure why this happens, but as you can see I have stored both occasions on different variables and can now use the second one.